# Safest way to run user-created scripts in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm writing an Electron application and I'd like to implement a scripting feature where the user can write JS scripts that automate tasks within the program. I want to be able to just pass an API object into the script for the user to interact with the application, and not allow it to access anything else.

What's the best practice for this sort of thing?